# Django OnetoOne key insert on perform_update not working

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

in my `models.py` I've

```
class Product(models.Model):
    
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

```
class Price(models.Model):
    
    code = models.OneToOneField(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price_tc = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    price_uc = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    price_bx = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to insert the price after each insertion of product to ensure the one to one.
So Implemented Django Perform Create in `views.py`

```
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
        ordering = ["code"]

        def perform_create(self, serializer):
           serializer.save()
           Price.objects.create(self.request.data["code"])
```

I get the error : Price.code must be a "Product" instance, so i swap to

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
        m = Product.objects.get(code=self.request.data["code"])
        Price.objects.create(code=m)
```

But still not working.

Comment: First rename code field to product in Price model and then add this `instance = super().perform_create(serializer)` in `perform_create` and then use this instance to create Price instance like this `Price.objects.create(product=instance)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with :

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save()
        Price.objects.create(code=instance)
```

It worked fine for me. You need to keep the instance beforce creating the ref table instance.